# how to send sms from my android app with my name on it instead my phone number?

Tags: android, sms

In my android app i send sms message to users after they sign in (they write their phone number in the registration form).
After they register i send sms to this phone to tell them welcome to the app or something like that (the content doesn't matter for now).
But what i want to be seen that the user get sms from my app name but instead it shown that the getting sms is from the phone number that they used to register.
I am using smsManager class to send the sms like this:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber,null,smsContent,null,null);
```

I have tried to change the second parameter from null to something else but nothing happened.
So how can i send sms that the users will see that it comes from my app?

Comment: The second parameter is for centre address and has nothing to do with names

Answer (score 0):

Check your `sendSMSMessage()` method.  The first parameter in `sendTextMessage()` should be your service number. You might have assigned the variable `phoneNumber` to `getText` from the user input.  Make sure you configure your own number in `phoneNumber`.

Comment: the first parameter is the phone that will receive the sms, i need it to be sent to the user's phone that he inputs, i just want that he will see that the sms comes from my app and not just from random number